How to UV unwrap long objects in order to use whole UV Map
I am modeling Katana, but anything similiar - swords, spears some columns and so on have this "problem". Blade is much longer than any other objects and they all use blade textile density.
One way would be to have seam in the middle of blade ( but that creates visible seam and still map isn't optimised as it could be).
Another way is to decrease scale down blade/scale up other island but that messes up with textile density.
One way which seems good I came across is to have rectangular UV map, 2048 x 1024 instead of standard square map 1024x1024. Does that affect anything when exported to engine - Unity or Unreal because once I was told map should all be square.

